# How do Sliver Overlord and Mirror Entity react together?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you activate [Mirror Entity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376409)'s ability to give all your creatures all creature types, can you then search for *any* creature in your library using [Sliver Overlord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSliver%20Overlord%5d)'s ability?

I understand that you don't "control" your library, but you do control **cards** on the battlefield and stack. But when you search your library, does it not become part of your stack, or at least doesn't the card you find in it?

Btw I stated **"cards"** because I know the word permanent means something else.

Comment: Are you asking whether or not you can search for Mirror Entity with Sliver Overlord?

Comment: You seem to have many misunderstandings. There is no “your stack”; there is only one stack. Your library never becomes part of the stack. You don’t control cards; you control objects such as spells and permanents (and those objects can be represented by a card).

Comment: I have rolled back your most recent edit.  On this site, each question post should only contain one question, and should not be edited to include additional questions or commentary on the answers, etc.  You can create a new post if you would like to ask a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Mirror Entity](https://magiccards.info/query?q=mirror%20entity)* does not allow *[Sliver Overlord](https://magiccards.info/query?q=sliver%20overlord)* to find any creature**

"Creatures you control" always refers only to the Battlefield, never to cards in any other zone (those will be referred to as "Creature Cards").

*Mirror Entity* interacts with *Sliver Overlord* in the following ways:

- *Sliver Overlord* can search for or gain control of *Mirror Entity*
- *Mirror Entity* can change the creature type of *Sliver Overlord* (and all other creatures (**on the battlefield**) you control) to all types.

There are no other interactions between these two cards.

Comment: Ye thats what i was hoping you wouldn't say but that does give me the answer i was looking for